# Xcode 4 hanging while compiling

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am compiling a small application with hardly 10 lines of code in Xcode 4. While compiling it seems to be hanging. But when i compile a small Hello World application, it seems to work fine. Earlier today it was working fine with a larger application. Could someone please tell me whats happening? and how can i overcome this issue and allow it to compile faster like before??

BR,
Suppi

Edited:

Ok, Xcode version 4.0.2, Ram size is 2GB, MAC OS X version 10.6.8.

and my code for the program i am running: 
I am basically checking to see how the interface between an Objective C and C works:

In my C file:

```
 void helloWorld()

 {
   printf("hellow Woeld c");
   hellowworldToObjC();
 }

void  hellowworldToObjC()
 {
    HelloWorldC();
 }
```

and Objective C class:

```
id refToSelf;
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    refToSelf = self; // Saving self in pointer
 }
 return self;
}
-(void)HelloWorldObjc
 {
  NSLog(@"Hello World from Objc C");
  [self HellowTestingC];
 }

 -(void)HellowTestingC
 {
  helloWorld();    
 }

 @end


  void HelloWorldC()
{
[refToSelf HelloWorldObjc];
}
```

Comment: We need more information: which version od Xcode 4, what version of OSX, huch ram,  which compiler, what kind of compiler settings, source code, ....

Comment: please have a look at the edited section

Comment: C does not know classes!

Comment: This doesn't happen only in this application. Previously i had an application that was compiling fast, now Xcode just seems to hang. Is there anything i should clear?? or any settings in Xcode i should change??

Answer (score 0):

Sample Xcode when it is "hanging" (and by "hanging", do you mean truly hanging or does it eventually work).

You also might want to leave `top -u` running in a terminal window and see how many pagein/pageout events occur when the "hang" happens.  If you are paging, it'll feel like a hang.

---

0 pageouts meanings you aren't swapping (the pageins are just the source files that are #included being read).

Post the sample.

Comment: Well i ran top -u, there are 0 pageouts and when the compiling started there was 60067 pageins now its 60561 pageins, and still no sign of app compiling.It just says "Compiling 1 of 4 source files".

Answer (score 0):

It was crazy with Xcode 4, the CPU was 190%, and Xcode 4 was not responding, so i went ahead and installed Xcode 3.2.6. Now all working fine :).

Comment: If you attach a Leaks instrument to Xcode you can see quite a number of memory leaks. It's possible one or more of those has contributed to your hang situation.